# Updating private repo plugins from admin?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, admin

Is it possible to update private repo plugins from the admin at all? Would love that functionality, especially for smaller projects that are installed where there's no CLI access.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible. The CP update process involves interactions with the Craft web services and the Craft web services don't have any information about the private repository for your site.

Comment: Would it be possible through a module or plugin?

Comment: Not a module for the same reason, but if it were a public plugin available on plugins.craftcms.com, then yes.